# What is the right syntax for adding Objective C @property into C++ class?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, objective-c++

In my C++ project I have a base class for interstitial ad:

```
class InterstitialAd
{
public:

    virtual void initialize(std::string unit_id) = 0;

    virtual void load() = 0;

    virtual void show() = 0;

    virtual void uninitialize() = 0;
};
```

and need to implement it of iOS with [Yandex Mobile Ads](https://yandex.ru/dev/mobile-ads/doc/ios/quick-start/interstitial.html?lang=en). According to their [docs](https://yandex.ru/dev/mobile-ads/doc/ios/quick-start/interstitial.html?lang=en) I need to add a `@property` and initialize it in my `initialize` method like this:

```
class YandexIosInterstitialAd : public InterstitialAd
{
    public:
        
        void initialize(std::string unit_id) override
        {
            //access interstitialAd here and add a code like this:

            self.interstitialAd = [[YMAInterstitialAd alloc] initWithAdUnitID:<your unique AdUnitId>];
            self.interstitialAd.delegate = self;
            [self.interstitialAd load];
        }

    private:
    
        //Need to declare this property 
        @property (nonatomic, strong) YMAInterstitialAd *interstitialAd;
}
```

what is the right syntax for that?

Ideally that `@property` should be declared inside my `YandexIosInterstitialAd` class, but not globally.

Comment: you can't do that, you can mix obejctive-c and c++ in a single file but c++ classes can't have objective-c properties

Comment: @where do I define `@property` then?

Comment: in an objective c class, though from a quick scan of their documentation I don't think you need a property at all, just a member variable. Though when you come to do `self.interstitialAd.delegate = self` you'll probably need an objective-c class

Comment: As long as you develop an iOS application, which anyway requires Cocoa Touch framework, you are required to have an Objective-C compatible compiler. Why can't you just use an Objective-C class here?

Comment: @TheDreamsWind It is a cross-platform app in QT that compiles for Android and Windows as well, so it has C++ class `InterstitialAd` base class that is implemented in different ways on different OSes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property is not required to be an Objective-C property, but you anyway need an Objective-C class to conform to the [`YMAInterstitialAdDelegate`](https://yandex.ru/dev/mobile-ads/doc/ios/ref/Protocols/YMAInterstitialAdDelegate.html) protocol which the `YMAInterstitialAd` object apparently requires in order to initialize itself.

Provided you compile the code with Objective-C++ syntax flag, you can just do the initialisation as follows:

```objc++
class YandexIosInterstitialAd : public InterstitialAd
{
public:

    YandexIosInterstitialAd(): delegate{ [TDWAdDelegate new] },
        interstitialAd{ [[YMAInterstitialAd alloc] initWithAdUnitID:<your unique AdUnitId>] } {
        interstitialAd.delegate = delegate;
        [interstitialAd load];
    }

private:

    id<YMAInterstitialAdDelegate> delegate;
    YMAInterstitialAd *interstitialAd;

};
```

Be advised, that ARC knows how and when to release the Cocoa objects, even if they are C++ class members, so you don't commonly need to do it manually. `TDWAdDelegate` in this case is just another Objective-C class which implements the `YMAInterstitialAd` protocol and looks something like that:

```objc
@interface TDWAdDelegate : NSObject <YMAInterstitialAdDelegate>

- (void)interstitialAdDidLoad:(YMAInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd;
- (void)interstitialAdDidClick:(nonnull YMAInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd;
/* ...other methods which your implementation requires... */

@end

@implementation TDWAdDelegate

- (void)interstitialAdDidLoad:(YMAInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
    // your implementation goes here
}

- (void)interstitialAdDidClick:(nonnull YMAInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
    // another method implementation
}

/* ...other methods which your implementation requires... */

@end
```

Comment: I need to add `@implementation YMAInterstitialAdDelegate` with `interstitialAdDidLoad` and `interstitialAdDidFailToLoad` methods, right?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky frankly i don't know which exact methods you need here. As far as I can see from [the documentation](https://yandex.ru/dev/mobile-ads/doc/ios/ref/Protocols/YMAInterstitialAdDelegate.html) most of the methods are optional, so it's probably up to you to decide which one needs customisation. I added a sample code for such a class which should give you a general idea of the approach